# Data conversion from VHDL to Verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I have the following variables defined in VHDL and I need to convert them into Verilog. I am first listing down the variables in VHDL and then my attempt at converting them:

**VHDL Code**

```
constant ValueLoad : std_logic_vector (11*24-1 downto 0) := 
b"0011010_0_0001111_000000000"&
b"0011010_0_0000000_000011111"&
b"0011010_0_0000001_000110111"&
b"0011010_0_0000010_001111001"&
b"0011010_0_0000011_000110000"&
b"0011010_0_0000100_011010010"&
b"0011010_0_0000101_000000001"&
b"0011010_0_0000110_001100010"&
b"0011010_0_0000111_001000011"&
b"0011010_0_0001000_000100000"&
b"0011010_0_0001001_000000001";


signal valueOut : std_logic;

signal registerA : std_logic_vector (11*24-1 downto 0); 
signal divider  : integer;
signal counterA : integer;
signal counterB : integer;
```

**My attempt to convert to Verilog**

```
wire valueOut;
wire [11*24-1:0] registerA;
wire divider;
wire counterA;
wire counterB;
```

Is this correct? Also, how do I define valueLoad in Verilog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how they will be assigned. If there are assigned inside `always` blocks, then it should be `reg` or `integer` types.

```
reg valueOut;
reg [11*24-1:0] registerA;
integer divider;
integer counterA;
integer counterB;
```

If they are assigned via `assign` statements, then they need to be net types.

```
wire valueOut;
wire [11*24-1:0] registerA;
wire signed [31:0] divider; // 'signed' to allow negative numbers
wire signed [31:0] counterA;
wire signed [31:0] counterB;
```

VHDL's `constant` should map to Verilog's `parameter`. VHDL uses `&` for contamination, Verilog contaminates surrounding a comma separates list with curly brackets:

```
parameter [11*24-1:0] ValueLoad = { 
  24'b0011010_0_0001111_000000000,
  24'b0011010_0_0000000_000011111,
  24'b0011010_0_0000001_000110111,
  24'b0011010_0_0000010_001111001,
  24'b0011010_0_0000011_000110000,
  24'b0011010_0_0000100_011010010,
  24'b0011010_0_0000101_000000001,
  24'b0011010_0_0000110_001100010,
  24'b0011010_0_0000111_001000011,
  24'b0011010_0_0001000_000100000,
  24'b0011010_0_0001001_000000001  };
```

Comment: The variables are defined outside the process in VHDL. From that, it seems it will be outside the "always" block. These variables are later assigned during the course of operation in the always block. Also, the range of the variables are Divider - 0 to 499, counterA - 0 to 28, counterB - 0 to 10. Considering this, do I still need to define the size of divider, counterA, and counterB?

Comment: With Verilog, you always need to defined the size (`integer` is synonymous with `reg signed [31:0]`). `wire counterA;` would be one bit. Since the range is 0-28 you could use `wire [4:0] counterA`. I'll let you figure out the widths of `divider` and `counterB`. FYI, synthesis will typically give an warning if the size is larger than necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that looks correct. Here's one way to define ValueLoad:

```
parameter [11*24-1:0] ValueLoad =
{24'b0011010_0_0001111_000000000,
 24'b0011010_0_0000000_000011111,
 24'b0011010_0_0000001_000110111,
 24'b0011010_0_0000010_001111001,
 24'b0011010_0_0000011_000110000,
 24'b0011010_0_0000100_011010010,
 24'b0011010_0_0000101_000000001,
 24'b0011010_0_0000110_001100010,
 24'b0011010_0_0000111_001000011,
 24'b0011010_0_0001000_000100000,
 24'b0011010_0_0001001_000000001};
```